# How do I join 2 pages in Windows 10 XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

How would I go about achieving a layout with 2 pages joined together? I can't seem to find anywhere else to find out how I would get a layout like this in xaml and c#. I tried using 2 frames side-by-side and navigating to one when the listitemitem was clicked, but it didn't work. I even tried different VisualStates for mobile and desktop but that also didn't work. I've also checked multiple sites, but cannot find what I'm looking for.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve: https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/layout/design-and-ui-intro#_____________Re_architect___________

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Output that you are looking for is Master/Detail Page.

Here is the GitHub [Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail)

I am not posting any code here because the sample is self explanatory.